# How to create Ceph OSDs on Partitions using cephadm, on ceph-pacific?

Tags: ceph

In the pacific version of Ceph, OSD creation is not allowing by cephadm on partitions.(We have NvMes with partitions). The command used is:

`ceph orch daemon add osd <host>:<device-path>`

The above command only accepts, disks or lvm, and throws error when a partition is provided.
As a tweak, pre-creating PV, VG, LV on the partition and providing the same to 'ceph orch' is possible, but the naming conventions for the Ceph VGs and LVs will not be met in this way.